# How can I get a SQL report with a group by that substitutes the group by value with a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table. It consists of rows that have a FormId or 1 or 2.  When the value is 1 then
the row is of type "Phrase", when it's 2 it is of type "Word".

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
             [PhraseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
             [English]  NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
             [FormId]   INT              NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

What I would like to do is to get a report like this:

```
Type      Count
Phrase    123
Word      456
```

Is there a way that I can get that kind of report that includes the word Phrase or Word instead of the numbers 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using case CASE and GROUP BY:

```
select
    case [FormId] 
        when 1 then 'Phrase' 
        when 2 then 'Word'
        else 'Not sure' end [Type],
    count(*) [Count]
from [dbo].[Phrase]
group by [FormId];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done commonly using `CASE` statement just like *Tim's* answer.

Here is a simpler approach using `CHOOSE`

```
SELECT Choose([Type], 'Phrase', 'Word'),
       Count(1)
FROM   dbo.albums
GROUP  BY [Type]
```

or Even `IIF`

```
SELECT IIF([Type] = 1, 'Phrase', 'Word'),
       Count(1)
FROM   dbo.albums
GROUP  BY [Type]
```

Both answer's works on `SQL SERVER 2012` and above

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FormID AS [Type], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM [dbo].[Phrase]
    GROUP BY FormID
)
SELECT CASE WHEN t.[Type] = 1 THEN 'Phrase'
            WHEN t.[Type] = 2 THEN 'Word'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS Type,
       t.Count
FROM cte t
```

Comment: You don't need `CTE/Dervied table` for this. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT IIF([FormId] = 1,'Phrase','Word') AS [Type] FROM [Phrase])
SELECT Type,count(*) AS Count FROM cte GROUP BY Type
```

I'm assuming that FormID can only be 1 or 2